# Are there yet Optical Magnetic Mirrors (OMMs) which reflect via interaction with the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, reflection, nanoscience, optical-materials

**update 2021:** As the question has remained unanswered for five years and the field of [optical metamaterials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial) has advanced, I think this question can be revisited.

---

The most familiar mirror relies on reflection from a metal, where the very strong interaction of the electric field component of the EM wave with the conduction electrons produces a reflected wave.

[Dielectric mirrors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_mirror) rely on the weaker interaction of the electric field with bound electrons, and a periodic modulation of the dielectric constant (alternating quarter wave thicknesses) builds up a reflected wave with high efficiency.

Both of those reflect due to the interaction of the electric field with electrons - be they bound or free.

*However*, the paper [Optical Magnetic Mirrors](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1464-4258/9/1/L01/meta) (Schwanecke et al. 2007 J. Opt. A: Pure Appl. Opt. 9 L1) begins with:

> **Abstract:** We report the first demonstration of an optical magnetic mirror achieved by nanostructuring a metal surface. It reverses the magnetic field of an incident wave upon reflection, acting as an ‘optical frequency superconductor’.

The introduction goes on to say:

> A magnetic mirror imposes extremely unusual electromagnetic boundary conditions: it does not reverse the electric field of a light wave upon reflection, but reverses the magnetic field. This property renders it distinctly different from a normal mirror, which instead reverses the electric field of a reflected wave...

And so the working definition of a magnetic mirror here seems to be a surface which produces a reflection without reversing the direction of the electric field, *but instead reversing the direction of the magnetic field*.

However it's not clear to me if this is due to the interaction with the magnetic field directly.

In the paper [Optical Magnetic Mirrors without Metals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.1308) (also [here](https://www.osapublishing.org/optica/abstract.cfm?uri=optica-1-4-250) Liu et al. 2014, Vol. 1, No. 4, 250) a nano-patterned purely dielectric surface is said to be an Optical Magnetic Mirror (OMM). I understand that the effect is due resonant modes within the dielectric patterns, and some of these modes are called 'electric' and some 'magnetic' as a naming convention, somewhat like there are TE and TM modes in a dielectric fiber waveguide. However, *aren't these still due to the interaction of the electric field*?

**Question:** Are there surfaces, or relatively thin nano-structures which reflect light *via interaction with the magnetic field* of the wave? Is there a physics distinction between that magnetic interaction, and a patterned surface that simply passes the test of not inverting the electric field?